# Code keeps returning 255 or -1073741819 when type casting char to string

Tags: c++, casting, runtime-error, codeblocks, string-conversion

This is a code for converting a string to lowercase letters. I used the idea of the ASCII value difference between uppercase and lower case letters in alphabet being 32. I am using codeblocks. The code does the conversion but gives this error. Why am I getting an error in this case, although there is no error in casting string to char? How do I correct this?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

string convertlow (string input )
{
    char letters[255];
    int ascii[255];

     for (int i=0;i<255;i++)
     {
         letters[i]=input[i];
         ascii[i]=(int)letters[i];

         if (ascii[i] < 91)
         {
             ascii[i] = ascii[i] + 32;
             letters[i] = (char) ascii[i];
             input[i] = letters[i];
         }
    }

    return input;
}

int main()
{
    string in;
    cin >> in;

    cout << "The lowercase version is: \n" << convertlow(in);
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: You are probably accessing out of range elements if your string is less than 255 chars long

Comment: [std::tolower](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) already exists.

Comment: [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). And -1073741819 is 0xC0000005 which is a very common error you can find on SO

Answer (score 1):

You should change:

```
if (ascii[i]<91)
{
    ascii[i]=ascii[i]+32;
    letters[i]= (char)ascii[i];
    input[i]=letters[i];
}
```

to:

```
if(ascii[i] >= 'A' && asc[i] <= 'Z')
{
    ascii[i]   = ascii[i]+('a' - 'A');
    letters[i] = (char)ascii[i];
    input[i]   = letters[i];
}
```

But your problem is array out of range (string size should be less than 255). To solve this you can change your method to:

```
string convertlow (string input ){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < input.size() ; ++i){
        if(islower(input[i]) ){
            input[i] = tolower(input[i]);
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

**You need to include headers: `string` and `algorithm`**

Comment: You can simplify the latter example by removing the `islower()` check (it is erroneous anyway, you meant to use `!islower()` or `isupper()` instead) and using `std::transform()` instead of a manual loop: `std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(), ::tolower);`